# Target a particular collection from a JSON file in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm a beginner and learning Backbone.js. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Colletion:

```
app.Collections.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Models.IdModel,
    url: "/test/test_data.json"
})


var profileDataCollection = new app.Collections.UserCollection();

profileDataCollection.fetch({
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // returns JSON data
    }
});
```

Returned data from fetch():

```
{  
   "msg":[  
      {  
         "firstname":"Abc",
         "lastname":"Xyz"
      },
      {  
         "firstname":"Test",
         "lastname":"Test"
      },
      {  
         "firstname":"Klm",
         "lastname":"Nop"
      }
   ],
   "flash_message":"",
   "log":[  

   ]
}
```

Just wondering how can I get the collection here for "msg" property? So that I can pass the collection to my view like this:-

```
new app.Views.UsersView( { collection: profileDataCollection });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parse method to the collection like

```
parse: function(response){
   return response.msg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question, how can i pass the collection name to the view in this case ?

Comment: @LipakSahil You can pass anything like `new app.Views.UsersView( { collection: profileDataCollection, something: 'something' });`